# Spring user account enabled/disabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm trying to see if a user who's trying to login has an enabled or disabled account, to do this I have a field in my `User` domain called `active` which is set to true if a user is enabled and vice versa.

In my CustomUserDetailsService I have the following to see if a user who's logging in can log in:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    AdeyTrack.domain.User domainUser = userRepo.findByLogin(login);

    boolean enabled = domainUser.getActive(); // checking here if enabled
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    return new User(
            domainUser.getLogin(),
            domainUser.getPassword(),
            enabled,
            accountNonExpired, 
            credentialsNonExpired, 
            accountNonLocked,
            getAuthorities(domainUser.getRoles())
    );
}
```

This works.

I have two questions:

1. Am I doing this in the correct way?
2. At the moment if a user who is logging in has a disabled account, just gets a "incorrect username/password" error, can I do anything so that I can make a callback which informs the user that their account is disabled?

Thanks.